# How to have express server make an initial http request before serving static files

Tags: node.js, web-services, express

I have a basic express server being used for an api server and serving static files for a react app like so:

```
app.use(express.static('/public'))
app.use('/api', apiRouter)
```

When a user initially loads the app, I need to retrieve data from a different server that I'll need for the api server before serving up the static files. Is there a way to have express make an initial http request to another server and cache the results on the server before serving up the static files?

Ideally, I want the server to make this request only once (when the user initially loads the app). I've looked into using express middleware, but am having trouble figuring out where to insert the middleware so that it only gets called when the files are served up.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Static files are static - so why do you need to contact another server first?  Or maybe your static files aren't really static?  Please explain what you're really trying to do.  Only then, can we answer accurately.

Comment: You could certainly have express middleware that contacts another server and caches the result before allowing routing to continue on to your static routing, but why in the world you would want to do that is a mystery.

Comment: I need to cache the results for my api server. I've edited the question to make it clearer. Middleware seem appropriate in this case, but is there a way to insert it such that it's only called once when the user requests the static assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you really want to only make a request once to some outside server, then you should probably just do it upon server startup.  There's really no reason to wait until some request comes in if you're going to cache the result anyway and it doesn't matter what route or what user is making the first request.

But, if you want to trigger it only when a request comes in, then you can use middleware to do so.  An outline of the middleware could look something like this:

```
let cachedResult;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (cachedResult) {
        next();
    } else {
        request(..., (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                 cachedResult = ....
                 next();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you want the middleware to ONLY execute when a static resource is requested, then you need some way of determining which incoming requests are for static resources and which are not.

The code you show:

```
app.use(express.static('/public'))
```

checks the `public` sub-directory for a match for any request which isn't very helpful.  If you would prefix all static resources with a prefix such as `/static`, then you could target only your static files like this:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('/public'));
```

And, you could run the middleware only for the static files like this:

```
app.use('/static', (req, res, next) => { ... });
app.use('/static', express.static('/public'));
```

Comment: @lu1000 - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will also earn you some stackoverflow reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

A simple request example could look like:

```
var request = require('request');
request({
        url: "https://some.url.com",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "content-type" : "application/json" },
        json: payload
    },
    function (error, response, data) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            //handle request
        }
        else {
            callback({ "errorMessage": "There was an error with the request" });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first: caching. Define a variable or a module that will be accessible to your future middleware:

#### ./cache.js

```
const cache = {};
module.exports = cache;
```

This module will hold users' data, like:

```
{
  'id00001': {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    birthday: 1488700668567
  },
  'id00002': {
    email: 'baz@bar.com',
    birthday: 1488700668590
  },
  // etc...
}
```

Next, use Request and Express middleware:

#### ./app.js

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express();

const cache = require('./cache'),
  request = require('request');

const getUserDataMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // assuming you have a mechanism to identify your users already somehow
  let user = req.user,
    id = user.id;

  // if data is not in cache
  if (!cache[id]) {

    request.get({
      url: 'http://getuserdata.com/' + id,
      json: true
    }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
      }

      // save received data to cache
      cache[id] = body;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    // you have your user data in cache, do whatever you want now
    next();
  }
};


app.use('/public', getUserDataMiddleware, express.static('./public'));
```

Comment: I like the cache module implementation. I think I will do something similar, thanks!

Comment: The best thing about this approach is that you can `require` this module from any other place in your app, and the data it's holding will be consistent everywhere.